# How to pull specific values from a string?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, jspdf

The project I am working on is a todo-list that has the ability to render a pdf using jsPDF. I need to be able to extract or pull (I am not sure what the correct codding term would be) specific attributes from that string so that I can print it as text using jsPDF.

The string I have is:

```
[{"content":"Test","category":"important","done":false,"createdAt":1659908150914},{"content":"Clean Room","category":"important","done":false,"createdAt":1659912937851}]
```

Now there are a few factors that make this complicated. Firstly, I only want the value(s) in quotes after content. In this case that would be Test and Clean Room. The other difficult part would be assigning them each a separate ID so that they can be printed using jsPDF.

I have spent a while trying to figure out the best way to do it, but this is actually my first coding project, so I am not quite sure what to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you expecting an array of objects like `{ id: 0, content: 'Test' }`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if it's a string, you have to convert it into a json object with the [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method, like so

```
var jsobj = JSON.parse('[{"content":"Test","category":"important","done":false,"createdAt":1659908150914},{"content":"Clean Room","category":"important","done":false,"createdAt":1659912937851}]');
```

Then you simply access to your `content` field like this:

```
jsobj.forEach(k => {
          
             console.log(k.content);

          });
```